# How can I use Github packages Docker registry in Kubernetes dockerconfigjson?

Tags: github, kubernetes, docker-registry

How can I pull `docker.pkg.github.com` Docker images from within Kubernetes cluster?

Currently, the Github Docker registry requires authentication even for packages from public Github repositories.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. Create new Github Personal Access Token with `read:packages` scope at https://github.com/settings/tokens/new.
2. Base-64 encode `<your-github-username>:<TOKEN>`, ie.:

   ```
   $ echo -n VojtechVitek:4eee0faaab222ab333aa444aeee0eee7ccc555b7 | base64
   <AUTH>
   ```

   *Note: Make sure not to encode a newline character at the end of the string.*
3. Create kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson secret

   A) Create secret manually:

   ```
   $ echo '{"auths":{"docker.pkg.github.com":{"auth":"<AUTH>"}}}' | kubectl create secret generic dockerconfigjson-github-com --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/dev/stdin
   ```

   B) Or, create .yml file that can be used in `kubectl apply -f`:

   ```
   kind: Secret
   type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
   apiVersion: v1
   metadata:
     name: dockerconfigjson-github-com
   stringData:
     .dockerconfigjson: {"auths":{"docker.pkg.github.com":{"auth":"<AUTH>"}}}
   ```

   *Note for GitOps: I strongly recommend not to store the above file in plain-text in your git repository. Hydrate the value in your CD pipeline or encrypt/seal the file with tools like https://github.com/mozilla/sops or https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets.*
4. Now, you can reference the above secret from your pod's spec definition via `imagePullSecrets` field:

   ```
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: your-container-name
       image: docker.pkg.github.com/<ORG>/<REPO>/<PKG>:<TAG>
     imagePullSecrets:
     - name: dockerconfigjson-github-com
   ```

Comment: When I just copy-and-paste what you wrote, I got "error: error validating "secret.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Secret.stringData..dockerconfigjson): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.Secret.stringData: got "map", expected "string"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false" error.

Comment: @Sam that's weird, I don't get this error. Perhaps try using `data` instead of `stringData`. But you'll have to base64 encode your secret value.

Comment: @Sam You can use "data" instead of "stringData" and put the value in single quotes:
'{"auths":{"docker.pkg.github.com":{"auth":"<AUTH>"}}}'

Comment: The same process above also works for pulling images from the newer GitHub Packages registry (ghcr.io) location.  Just replace references to docker.pkg.github.com with ghcr.io.

Comment: @Sam could you fix that error?

Answer (score 10):

I had to migrate from docker.pkg.github.com to ghcr.io to get this to work with containerd: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/migrating-to-the-container-registry-from-the-docker-registry

Don't forget to create the token with `read:packages`:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry dockerconfigjson-github-com \
 --dry-run=true \
 --docker-server=https://docker.pkg.github.com \
 --docker-username=<username> \
 --docker-password=<https://github.com/settings/tokens/new> \
 --namespace=default -o yaml
```

Add the pull secret:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: your-container-name
    image: docker.pkg.github.com/<ORG>/<REPO>/<PKG>:<TAG>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: dockerconfigjson-github-com
```

Answer (score 5):

Important notice as github changed it primary domain name from docker.pkg.github.com to ghcr.io ([Release Note](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/migrating-to-the-container-registry-from-the-docker-registry)):

secrets.yml now should look like

```
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dockerconfigjson-github-com
stringData:
  .dockerconfigjson: {"auths":{"ghcr.io":{"auth":"<AUTH>"}}}
```

And the corresponding deployment spec

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: your-container-name
    image: ghcr.io/<ORG>/<REPO>/<PKG>:<TAG>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: dockerconfigjson-github-com
```

Other than described, the old version did not work for me anymore.
Maybe this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for folks who are deploying a private ghcr.io image to a kubernetes cluster from within a Github Actions Workflow:

1. You need to create a new token with `read:packages` scope. You can use this link: https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=read:packages
2. Add the token as a repository secret `KUBERNETES_GHCR_PACKAGES_TOKEN`
3. Add the following code to your `.github/workflows/[action].yml`:

```yaml
# ...
jobs:
  build:
    name: Deploy to kubernetes cluster
    steps:
    # ... checkout, save x509 keys 
    - name: "Generate ghcr.io imagepullsecret"
        run: |
          DOCKER_AUTH_TOKEN=$(echo -n "${GHCR_USER}:${KUBERNETES_GHCR_PACKAGES_TOKEN}" | base64)
          DOCKER_CONFIG_JSON="{\"auths\":{\"${DOCKER_REGISTRY}\":{\"auth\":\"${DOCKER_AUTH_TOKEN}\"}}}"
          echo "
          kind: Secret
          type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
          apiVersion: v1
          metadata:
            name: dockerconfigjson-ghcr-io
          stringData:
            .dockerconfigjson: '${DOCKER_CONFIG_JSON}'
          " > "${KUBERNETES_DIR}/dockerconfigjson-ghcr-io.yml"
        env:
          KUBERNETES_DIR: "k8"
          GHCR_USER: "${{ github.actor }}"
          KUBERNETES_GHCR_PACKAGES_TOKEN: "${{ secrets.KUBERNETES_GHCR_PACKAGES_TOKEN }}"
          DOCKER_REGISTRY: ghcr.io

      - name: Deploy to Kubernetes
        run: |
          # Of course you need to specify server and x509 login certificates
          kubectl apply -f "${KUBERNETES_DIR}"
        env:
          KUBERNETES_DIR: "k8"
```