# Unable to pull public docker image packages from GitHub through Kubernetes

Tags: docker, github, kubernetes, continuous-integration

I created a [sample Node.js project](https://github.com/lethalbrains/intense_omega) in GitHub and created a docker image for the same. I uploaded the docker image as a package in the same repository. This is a public repo. I created a kubernetes config yaml file with this image as the pods image. Following is the yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: node-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: node-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: node-server
          image: docker.pkg.github.com/lethalbrains/intense_omega/io_service:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockerconfigjson-github-com
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  selector:
    component: node-server
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/inress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/
            backend:
              serviceName: server-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 3000
```

After I apply this file using Kubectl and check the pods details, I get an ImagePullBackOff error.

[image]

I even tried [using this option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61912589/how-can-i-use-github-packages-docker-registry-in-kubernetes-dockerconfigjson) of using dockerconfigjson secret with Github Personal Access Token but still the sam result.

Edit:

Added error message from pods describe 
[image]

Comment: Run `kubectl describe pod` on it to see the events, it will give you a more detailed error message.

Comment: @coderanger, Added the error message from the pods describe

Comment: Can you check if you run docker pull on the node works?

Comment: @hoque, I am able to pull the docker container from my machine. But I had already configured my github access keys in my environment. So I tried from a different machine and I got the following error -  `no basic auth credentials`

Comment: I think problem is with provided imagepullsecrets  .  please ensure you call pull image with your provided credential

Comment: @hoque  I created the imagepullsecrets as mentioned in the solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61912589/how-can-i-use-github-packages-docker-registry-in-kubernetes-dockerconfigjson

Comment: @Rahul, check this documentation [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).

Comment: @Crou, Thanks. Since its a public repo, I have been assuming the packages are also public, is it not the case?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with GitHub registry which is being discussed [here](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/3291).

What I can recommend is to push the image to [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/) or if create private repo which you can read about at [Using a private Docker Registry with Kubernetes](https://blog.cloudhelix.io/using-a-private-docker-registry-with-kubernetes-f8d5f6b8f646).

There seems to be a workaround but I did not tested that.
It's published by [@sudomaxime](https://github.com/sudomaxime) and available [here](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/3291#issuecomment-640285711):

> Here's a nasty little workaround for thoses who:
>
> - Don't mind  *loosing*  blue/green deploys until this is resolved
> - Don't mind 10-15 secs app start-up time
> - Use docker swarm / docker stack deploys
> - Use CI scripts for deployment
>
> In your CI scripts call:
>
> ```
> $ docker stack rm {{ your_stack_name }}
> $ until [ -z $(docker stack ps {{ your_stack_name }} -q) ]; do sleep 1; done
> $ docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c docker-compose.yml {{ your_stack_name }}
> ```
>
> Basically you ask Docker scheduler to stop all the services under {{ your_stack_name }} orchestrator. A little knack of docker swarm is that  `docker stack rm`  will immediately return even if some services are not properly closed chich may cause networking errors when you try to deploy again. That's why we use a small inline script  `until [ -z $(docker stack ps {{ your_stack_name }} -q) ]; do sleep 1; done`  to wait for the proper return.
>
> Hopes it saves a few folks headaches. I guess a similar  **temporary**  fix will help you out.
>
> This is quite a frustrating issue, for our apps that MUST use blue/green deploys we bought a private repo to fix the problem.